# how to write an IK plugin in moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, plugin, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a IK plugin in moveit for my own robot just like PR2. I read the IK plugin of PR2 but didn't know how to write it exactly. I wonder what function I should write to connent the IK to moveit. The ROS version I use is Indigo.Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228406/how-to-write-an-ik-plugin-in-moveit/) by [gutianqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26191/gutianqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are just trying to use a different robot with MoveIt!, you don't need a new IK plugin. The IK plugin is what Moveit uses for computing the inverse kinematics and the default one uses [KDL](http://www.orocos.org/kdl) which is a generic solver that should work for any kind of robot arm.

All Moveit! needs to work with a new robot is your robot's URDF file and you have to go through the MoveIt! setup wizard.

If you already knew this and have tried the default plugin and are not happy with the performance, there are two easy alternative IK plugins that I am aware of, the OpenRave [IKFast plugin](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ikfast/html/doc/ikfast_tutorial.html) and the [Trac-IK](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik.git) one. The IKFast method creates a solver that is custom to your robot since it is an analytical solver, Trac-IK is similar to the KDL one (both are numerical solvers) which *should* work for all robots.

If you have went through the trouble of solving the analytical IK solution for your arm by hand, you can make you own plugin from scratch, but that is not too easy.

Long story short: You shouldn't need to make your own plugin unless you've tried the default one and are not happy with it.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gutianqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26191/gutianqi/) on 2016-03-07**:
Thank you very much ! I have tried  [IKFast](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ikfast/html/doc/ikfast_tutorial.html) plugin but this tutorial in Moveit seems not that right when I typed
sudo apt-get install openrave0.8-dp-ikfast .
the system couldn't find the openrave0.8 install package.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-03-08**:
Have you tried the default MoveIt plugin? Did it not work?

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2016-03-21**:
The TRAC-IK plugin should work if KDL does not.  There is a list of over a dozen or so common robot platforms on the TRAC-IK Bitbucket page with IK results.  If you have a URDF, I can run a quick test and tell you how well KDL and TRAC-IK perform.

**Comment by [kmohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27437/kmohan/) on 2016-07-26**:
@pbeeson and @Airuno2L Does the TRAC-IK plugin support mimic joints? KDL doesn't seem to support it and I am having a hard time with the IKFast plugin.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-07-28**:
I'm not sure, are you trying to do IK with a parallel manipulator?

**Comment by [kmohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27437/kmohan/) on 2016-08-01**:
@Airuno2L It is not a parallel manipulator. However, it does have a parallel linkage connecting the end effector to the base.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-08-02**:
It sounds like a closed-loop mechanism, maybe a picture added to the question would help? I don't think KDL or even URDF has support for closed-loop structures but I could be wrong.

**Comment by [kmohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27437/kmohan/) on 2016-08-02**:
@Airuno2L , it is not a closed loop structure. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxySSG5xgDizRE5yYWRwcHhCVUk) is a picture of my robot. The end effector is not included in the picture and would be attached to the red colored gear-like link (called "driver") at the very end

**Comment by [jeroendm](https://answers.ros.org/users/36697/jeroendm/) on 2018-07-28**:
It would still be interesting to have some pointers to information on the original question (building a custom IK plugin). Information on it seems difficult to find, apart from going to the source code of MoveIt!.